# Why does my code not converge in VBA using the Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project to create a code in Visual Basic for Applications that allows me to calculate the titration curve of any n-protic acid using the Newton-Raphson method. The problem is that the function at any concentration of acid (Caci) and at any new Metal concentration (M) does not converge to any H concentration value (Hnew).

```
Sub Primer_intento_que_Dios_se_apiade()

'Esto para definir de que tipo serán las variables
Dim n As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim t  As Integer 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel se debe borrar posteriormente
Dim el As Integer 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel
Dim Kw As Double
Dim Mini As Double
Dim M As Double
Dim VM As Double
Dim Cacini As Double
Dim Caci As Double
Dim Vali As Double
Dim Vf As Double
Dim VMtit As Double
Dim Vfsln As Double

'Todo esto es simplemente para preguntar las variables que se le necesitan preguntar al usuario y definir la constante K
t = 1 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel se debe borrar posteriormente
el = 10 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel se debe borrar posteriormente pero no todo una parte es la primera columna de nuestra tabla :D
n = InputBox("Dime cuantos protones tiene tu ácido", "Número de protones", 1, 7000, 4000)
Kw = 10 ^ -14

ReDim B(n) As Double

For j = 1 To n Step 1
    B(n) = InputBox(" Dime el B" & j & " de tu ácido", "B´s", 2, 7000, 4000)
    Cells(t, 1) = j
    Cells(t, 2) = B(j) 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel se debe borrar posteriormente
    t = t + 1 'Esto es solo para visualizarlo en Excel se debe borrar posteriormente
Next j

Cacini = InputBox("Dime la concentración del acido (en M)", " Concentración del ácido ", 0.1, 7000, 4000)
Vali = InputBox("Dime el volumen de la sln del ácido (en mL)", "Vol del acido", 10, 7000, 4000)
Mini = InputBox("Dime la concentración de NaOH (en M)", " Concentración del NaOH ", 0.1, 7000, 4000)
VMtit = InputBox("Dime el volumen de la sln de NaOH que quieres ir añadiendo en la titulación (en mL)", "Vol del titulante", 0.5, 7000, 4000)

'Para definir hasta cuando va ir la titulación
Vf = ((n + 1) * Cacini * Vali) / Mini


Vfsln = Vali + Vf
Cells(8, 2) = Vfsln

Dim S1, S2, S3, S4 As Double
Dim Sd1, Sd2, Sd3, Sd4 As Double
Dim Hini As Double
Dim Hnew As Double
Dim Y As Double
Dim Tol As Double
Hini = 12
Hnew = 0
Y = Abs(Hnew - Hini)
Tol = 0.0000000001

For j = 1 To n Step 1
    S1 = B(j) * (Hini ^ (j + 2)) + S1
    S2 = B(j) * (Hini ^ (j + 1)) + S2
    S3 = B(j) * (Hini ^ (j)) + S3
Next j
For j = 1 To n - 1 Step 1
    S4 = (n - j) * B(j) * (Hini ^ (j + 1)) + S4
Next j

For j = 1 To n Step 1
    Sd1 = (j + 2) * B(j) * ((Hini) ^ (j + 1)) + Sd1
    Sd2 = (j + 1) * B(j) * ((Hini) ^ (j)) + Sd2
    Sd3 = B(j) * ((Hini) ^ (j - 1)) * j + Sd3
Next j
For j = 1 To n - 1 Step 1
    Sd4 = (n - j) * B(j) * ((Hini) ^ (j)) * (j + 1) + Sd4
Next j

'Método de Newton-Rapson

For VM = 0 To Vf Step VMtit
    Caci = (Cacini * Vali) / (Vali + VM)
    M = (Mini * VM) / (Vali + VM)
    Cells(el, 1) = VM ' Esto NO SE BORRA es la primera columna y el eje x de nuestra curva de titulación :D vamos que se puede
    el = el + 1
    While Y > Tol
        Hnew = Hini - (Polinomio(S1, S2, S3, S4, Kw, Hini, n, Caci, M) / DevPolinomio(Sd1, Sd2, Sd3, Sd4, Kw, Hini, n, Caci, M))
        Y = Abs(Hnew - Hini)
        Hini = Hnew
    Wend
Next VM
End Sub

Function Polinomio(S1, S2, S3, S4, Kw, Hini, n, Caci, M)

Polinomio = S1 + M * S2 - Caci * S4 - Kw * S3 + Hini ^ 2 + (M - n * Caci) * Hini - Kw

End Function

Function DevPolinomio(Sd1, Sd2, Sd3, Sd4, Kw, Hini, n, Caci, M)

DevPolinomio = Sd1 + M * Sd2 - Caci * Sd4 - Kw * Sd3 + 2 * (Hini) + (M - n * Caci)

End Function
```

Comment: Please indent and format your code for readability, and remove the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Should `B(n) = InputBox(...` be `B(j) = InputBox(...`? Also, `Dim S1, S2, S3, S4 As Double` only declares `S4` as `Double`. The other 3 variables are implicitly variants.

Comment: Perhaps because not every `Double` presicion variable has an exact representation in binary.